# Magento 2 Design Configuration edit action not shows

Tags: magento2, configuration

I'm new in Magento so I follow `YouTube` tutorials to change design but Edit action not shows on `Configuration Page`.
I just open **Content / Design / Configuration**
`Action` are empty, I'm unable to find edit action. How can I edit this.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have using any 3rd party modules and also check magento excpetion log and system .log

Comment: I don't use any 3rd party modules

Comment: Do indexing one  time

Comment: indexing means?

Comment: Asking to reindexing

Comment: Thanks @AmitBera I have create new setup of magento then i resolve this issue.